# ffmpeg hangs every two times on Mac

Tags: macos, video, ffmpeg, freeze

I want to use ffmpeg for video recording The list using

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -list_devices true -i ""
```

is:

```
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7f837dc0f180] AVFoundation video devices:
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7f837dc0f180] [0] FaceTime HD Camera
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7f837dc0f180] [1] Capture screen 0
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7f837dc0f180] AVFoundation audio devices:
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7f837dc0f180] [0] NoMachine Microphone Adapter
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7f837dc0f180] [1] Super_input
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7f837dc0f180] [2] BlackHole 16ch
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7f837dc0f180] [3] Built-in Microphone
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7f837dc0f180] [4] NoMachine Audio Adapter
```

The command I use for video recording is:

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -y -i "1:2" -r 12 -t 5 out.mov
```

It works fine! The video and the audio are both fine.

However, it will hangs every two times. The first time I run it it works fine, the second time I run it it hangs, and I need to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to stop it. The third time it works fine, the fourth time it hangs. It happens in both built-in terminal and iTerm2.

The screenshot when hanging is shown as:

[image: IMG:]

My OS is Mac Catalina. If I know how to solve it, it would be perfect.

Comment: I don't know what happen, but the problem seems solved automatically.

Comment: Oh, the problem appeared again today. Does anyone can help?

Comment: Have a look at the discussion on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16523746/ffmpeg-hangs-when-run-in-background